# Android screensaver in app if it's not used

Tags: java, android, eclipse, screen, screensaver

I created an android app. The screen never turns off:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Now I want to show a picture if the screen is not pressed for 5 minutes or something else. The app should not be closed, when pressing on the image the app should be open.

How can I realize that?

Comment: "How can I realize that?" -- what *specifically* do you need help with? For example, to display an image, use an `ImageView`.

Comment: I search the event, when the Android System says my app that the User didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would discourage you from taking this approach. Users expect to have a consistent user experience between various apps on their devices, and likely have a preference to how their device sleeps, either by having specified a sleep timeout or [displaying a daydream as introduced in Android 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Daydream).

If you'd like to provide users with the option to display a screensaver associated with your app, I suggest including a Daydream in your app and otherwise acknowledging the user's preferences.

*That being said*, if you cannot use Daydream, you could observe if the app is being used or not. Two things come to mind:

1. Have the root view of your activity intercept touch events to observe if any of its children have been touched.
2. Observe the activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()` to acknowledge that the activity is still being displayed.

You could then invoke a Runnable by posting it to a view using [`postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29), being wary to remove it when the activity is paused or the timer should be reset using [`removeCallbacks(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: Don't worry about the users, the app is running on tablets at public places! But the tablet's are running on Android 2.2, so there is no Daydream..

Comment: That would be an acceptable use case! I've updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: I tried a lot of examples which sets a OnTouchListener on a Layout, but if I press on something like a button, it doesn't register that.

Comment: You are likely consuming the touch event by returning true.

Comment: It do not change anything if I return true or false in the OnTouchListener of my RelativeLayout.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. You should be looking into onInterceptTouchEvent(), not the normal onTouchEvent() which propagates events in the wrong direction for your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!!!

I used that event:

```
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
    {

        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        // cancel my Timer

        return true;

    }
```

Thanks!!